# Can we edit questions that go off on some legal thing that isn't relavent?

Tags: discussion

JooJaa and I talked to the person who posted to ask about ownership of custom made clothes in chat. Maybe I am wrong, but being that we are on a legal discussion site, I took ownership to mean the design, not who controls the clothes.

Obviously, copyright and any law other than deciding whether the poster stole the clothes or not isn't relevant, because no one cares who designed the shirt if you are figuring out who owns it.

The question should be edited to allow people to figure out if the shirt was stolen or not instead of worded in the confusing way.

Further, the questions about cybersquatting regarding a company name being used in a site or game or whatever usually are about cybersquatting and the poster tries to make it sound like a first amendment issue.

Those questions should be reworded to ask about the right legal topic, which is cybersquatting.

Answer (score 5):

You can propose edits to a question by clicking the `edit` link under the question.  [Here is one guide that explains when and how you should edit another person's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120583/241697).

You can also `add a comment` to request clarification or recommend a substantive change in the post.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, comments are better than edits. Edits that interpret a question that could have more than one meaning are to be avoided unless there are comments from the person posting the question that support that interpretation.